React Native - Build command to run metro in terminal
I am running a React Native Project and the command I used to run the app is npx react-native run-android. But by using this command, the node.js window open separatly and I want that the metro or node.js will also open in my terminal.
So, If there is any command for this. Please let me know.

I'm not sure it's possible on Pure React Native. You might use Expo instead, which is also recommended

Try to use this command, it works for me.
npx react-native run-android --terminal


To run the metro in the same terminal just run the below command.
npx react-native start

and if you are using yarn
yarn start

